# Как получить остальные вкладки сущности Leads в api/v4 amocrm?

Tags: веб-программирование, api, crm

проблема следующая: недавно начал работу с api/v4 amocrm. Возникла потребность изменить значения полей custom_fields_values в сущности сделки (api/v4/leads). Я формулирую запрос, отправляю - получаю 200, все ок. Проблема в том, что я отправляю туда, *где этих полей нет*. Я делаю по документации просто запрос к leads, но там есть еще и разные вкладки. И по запросу GET я получаю данные с вкладки "Основное".

[image: Вкладка, с которой я получаю данные по запросу api/v4/leads]

Там полей, которые мне нужно поменять, нет. Мне нужно изменить поля вот здесь:

[image: Откуда я должен получить данные]

Как мне обратиться непосредственно к этой вкладке, и хотя бы получить данные с нее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, эти поля попросту пустые, а запрос GET /api/v4/leads возвращает поля со ВСЕХ вкладок. Нужно заполнить эти поля.